# OpenCV: YUV values of a grayscale image?

Tags: python, opencv, grayscale, yuv

Is it possible to calculate the values YUV of a graycale image ?

I found an article that confuses me: ***Interactive Image Colorization and Recoloring based on Coupled Map Lattices***. In which the authors propose an algorithm to color and recolor an image.

For colorization, they color grayscale images. The user scribble some regions of the image with the desired color which spreads itself automatically by the algorithm.

They use `YUV` color space to compare the values of `Y` between the current pixel and its neighbors. If the `Y` value of a neighbor is stronger than the current pixel sets its `U` and `V` values to those of the neighbor (attacker).

My problem: how can I cancluate the `YUV` values of a given pixel of a grayscale image ?

Or may be a better question: how do they compare in that article the valyes of UV of each pixel since they set them to 0 (grayscale) in the start ?

Comment: Yes, the YUV values for a grayscale image L are `Y = L; U = 0; V = 0`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, that is the answer I got from an other forum, thank you very much @beaker

Comment: @beaker if so, is there a way to access `U` and `V` values of a grayscale image (even if they are null) ? in RGB I just use `image[i,j,0]` to access the blue channel, for example, but I think grayscale images can access only the` L` value ?

Comment: The answer is essentially the same as the one I gave here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037987/adding-an-alpha-channel-to-a-monochrome-image-using-open-cv-python/27047953#27047953 except you'll want to do `img_Lzz = cv2.merge((L,z,z));` to create a full, modifiable LUV version of your image.

Comment: @beaker Any reference for "the YUV values for a grayscale image L are Y = L; U = 0; V = 0"?

Comment: @John The most simplified reference is from Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/about-yuv-video). Notice that `Y' = 0.299R + 0.587G + 0.114B`. This should look familiar as an RGB to grayscale conversion. Next, remember that in a grayscale image, R=G=B. See [OpenCV: Color conversions](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html). For grayscale to RGB conversion, Y is simply assigned to each channel. Finally, from the Microsoft link above, `U = B - Y'` and `V = R - Y'`. Since R=G=B=Y', both `B - Y'` and `R - Y'` are zero.

Comment: @John You can also have a look at the conversion formulas from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#SDTV_with_BT.470).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are three questions in one:

1. *Is it possible to calculate the values YUV of a graycale image?*

   Yes.
2. *My problem: how can I cancluate the YUV values of a given pixel of a grayscale image?*

   You could treat your grayscale image as a RGB image and then convert that to YUV:

   ```
   cv::Mat1b image;
   cv::Mat3b image_BGR, image_YUV;
   cv::cvtColor( image, image_BGR, COLOR_GRAY2BGR );
   cv::cvtColor( image_BGR, image_YUV, COLOR_BGR2YUV );
   ```
3. *Or may be a better question: how do they compare in that article the valyes of UV of each pixel since they set them to 0 (grayscale) in the start?*

   I suggest you post that question as a separate question (and add a link to the PDF of the paper).

Comment: Does that answer your unfinished question in your comment? (updated my answer)

Comment: Thank you. I did what you said, but I noticed each BGR or grayscale image i convert to YUV colorspace, I never get the YUV values but always BGR values when i run `print image_in_yuv[i,j,0]` I get Blue but not `Y` value. Why is this ?

Comment: A pixel in your grayscale image has the value L. That same pixel in the BGR image has the value (B,G,R)=(L, L, L). And the Y value of that same pixel in the YUV image is also L. So, you have Y=B=L. @beaker explained it already in the comments above.